# how to post value to multiple pages via a href in php?

Tags: php, post

I have 3 pages. `index.php`, `iframe-a.php`, `iframe-b.php`. the relation as below.

index.php

```
<a href="iframe-a.php?search=something" target="frame_a">something</a>
//a group of a link, so I do not consider `from`  
<iframe src="iframe-a.php" width="600px" height="600px" name="frame_a" />
```

iframe-a.php

```
$_GET['search'];//do some job
<iframe src="iframe-b.php" width="600px" height="300px" name="frame_b" />
```

iframe-b.php

```
$_GET['search'];//do some job
```

I search many topics, some question only about in a `form` type. I wonder to know how to post value to multiple pages via `a href` in php? I want pass the value not only in `iframe-a.php`, but also in `iframe-b.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all 3 pages are in effect refreshing, only index.php needs to know what is going on. Index.php tells the iframe pages that the url to load in the  scr is.

```
<?php
echo '<iframe src=iframe-a.php?search=' . $string_passed_to_index.php . '>';
```

[That way you only have to sanitize it once.] No, bad Cups! I take that bit back.

Comment: yes, that's true, post just via url, so just do something like this. That is a great help. Thanks a lot : }

Comment: Actually, that is a dangerous comment of mine "you only have to sanitize it once" Anyone can find that url and submit anything into it - I take that back, you will always need to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript for this. Attach some code to the onClick event of the link and refresh both iframes manually.

**Edit:** Something like this (using jQuery)

```
$('a#your-link-id').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe-a').attr('src', 'iframe-a.php?search=something');
    $('#iframe-b').attr('src', 'iframe-b.php?search=something');
});
```

Note: Set the proper `id` attributes in your HTML.

Comment: could u give me some advanced code? I just know little about jquery ajax post, but have no idea to write something like this. Thanks.

Comment: nice work. a little pity, mr.cups give me the answer a few minutes earlier, it also work. But also thanks for your kindly help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a client problem. PHP don't know anything about iframes or targets. It only processes HTTP requests.